# How to create a cross table to fill in values for new column created in SQL ORACLE

Tags: transformation

I have a column that has both state and country codes. Problem is that we need to separate this out into 2 columns (new_state and new_country) order to effectively use the data. I was initially thinking of using an insert command for each distinct state_country code but that didn't seem efficient. I'm reading and looks like cross table is the way to go but was wondering if someone can shed light on how to get that ball rolling. Thanks all.

```
STATE_COUNTRY   NEW_STATE   NEW_COUNTRY
     PA                      
     VA
     NY
     JP
     KR
```

This is what the outcome should look like.

[image]

Comment: Really not clear what you want. Please add sample data and desired result.

Comment: I've got about 10000 rows in the STATE_COUNTRY column. I want to parse what is in that column into NEW_STATE and NEW_COUNTRY. I was initially thinking of a case statement. CASE WHEN STATE_COUNTRY = PA then PA. I would essentially do this for every distinct value. There are some foreign country codes that are also included and would like to place them as 'NA' since they are not an actual state. Hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: I've updated my original post to show what am I trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need some kind of reference ('cross') table that indicates whether a `STATE_COUNTRY` is either an American state or a foreign country.

First of all, create and fill that table:

```
CREATE TABLE american_states
(
  abbreviation VARCHAR2(2),
  description  VARCHAR2(64)
);

INSERT INTO american_states (abbreviation, description)
  VALUES ('PA', 'Pennsylvania');
INSERT INTO american_states (abbreviation, description)
  VALUES ('VA', 'Virginia');
INSERT INTO american_states (abbreviation, description)
  VALUES ('NY', 'New York');
...
```

Then, update your original table, using that reference table:

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET new_state = state_country,
       new_country = 'US'
 WHERE state_country IN (SELECT abbreviation FROM american_states);

UPDATE my_table
   SET new_state = 'NA',
       new_country = state_country
 WHERE state_country NOT IN (SELECT abbreviation FROM american_states);
```

**UPDATE:**
All of a sudden I got the impression that you're not working in a database but on an Excel sheet....

Comment: I did that to quickly show you the data, but I am running this in a db. So after much thinking on designing and optimizing. I created a cross table and now joining against my data set to this crosstable and that seemed to fill all my values correctly. Now my next problem is that these states are not properly being displayed on my map visualization which is a whole new problem. Thanks for helping me get the ball rolling. Much appreciated.